# error in model fit in titanic dataset using TFLEARN

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, kaggle, tflearn

I am practising how TF learn works using pandas and titanic dataset. I think I got the hang of it but while fitting my model it crashes and I am not sure why. I guess it has something to do with the way I converted the `inputX and inputY` but I am not really sure, I thought it is right.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn
import pandas as pd

# Download the Titanic dataset
from tflearn.datasets import titanic
titanic.download_dataset('titanic_dataset.csv')

from tflearn.data_utils import load_csv
dataframe = pd.read_csv('titanic_dataset.csv')

# okay lets drop the rest of the stuff from the table and keep those.
dataframe = dataframe.drop(["name", "ticket"], axis=1)

#lets change sex female/male to 1 and 0
dataframe['sex'].replace(['female','male'],[1,0],inplace=True)

# lets convert them so the tlearn can use doesnt crash
inputX = dataframe.loc[:, ['pclass', 'sex', 'age', 'sibsp', 'parch', 'fare']].as_matrix()
dataframe.loc[:, ("survived2")] = dataframe["survived"] == 0           
dataframe.loc[:, ("survived2")] = dataframe["survived2"].astype(int)
inputY = dataframe.loc[:, ["survived", "survived2"]].as_matrix()

def NN():
    net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 6])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
    net = tflearn.regression(net)
    # This model assumes that your network is named "net"    
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    return model

# Define model
model = NN()
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
# Training
model.fit(inputX, inputY, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True, batch_size=100, n_epoch=8)
```

Here is the error picture[image]

Comment: No error... for me.

Comment: Training Step: 95  | total loss: 0.61928 | time: 0.031s
| Adam | epoch: 008 | loss: 0.61928 - acc: 0.6695 -- iter: 1100/1178
Training Step: 96  | total loss: 0.61247 | time: 1.046s
| Adam | epoch: 008 | loss: 0.61247 - acc: 0.6765 | val_loss: 0.59717 - val_acc: 0.6489 -- iter: 1178/1178

Comment: @ScottBoston what thee....

Comment: @ScottBoston I am using ipythonnotebook, could that be a problem?

Comment: As well as I am too.  Maybe upgrade all packages?

Comment: I downloaded all this yesterday....

Comment: @ScottBoston Weird, it works in the console...

Comment: Just restart the kernel, it does this error sometimes.